# Google App engine not using the auto-generated https url after deployment of custom flexible runtime apache powered yii2 application

Tags: apache, google-app-engine, yii2

I deployed a dockerized yii2 application on google app engine inorder for this to work my application needs to listen on port 8080. I managed to get apache to listen on port 8080. The application deployed successfully but when I try to access it on the https autogenerated URL by app engine it always redirects to the HTTP version. For example say the url is https://flex-dot-[projectId].appspot.com it redirects to 
http://flex-dot-[projectId].appspot.com. Is this a normal behaviour or am I missing something? Keep in mind I know I can add custom domain then add SSL through that means but I just want to be sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: I just tried to replicate this by deploying the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart) for App Engine Flex but I'm not getting redirected. Can you please share details of what you did deployed and what is different between your application and yaml configuratuon and the quickstart?

Comment: I deployed a yii2 application with this yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.2-apache
 base image and I rewrote part of the default config with this command "CMD sed -i "s/80/$PORT/g" /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf && docker-php-entrypoint apache2-foreground" to listen on port 8080. My app.yaml is set to custom runtime and flex environment.

Comment: Since you are using a lot of custom made code and configurations please share a minimal reproducible sample with us. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)